# How can I set hight of Vertical control in ConstraintLayout in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I hope to set the height of Vertical control *VerticalSeekBar* as maximum height between *btnMenu* control and *btnAction* control.

But *Layout B* (The result is *Image B*) isn't what I need, so I have to define the height value of *VerticalSeekBar* as a fixed 200dp, you can see the *Layout A* (The result is *Image A*).

BTW,  the VerticalSeekBar control is hosted at  https://github.com/lukelorusso/VerticalSeekBar

**Layout A**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_exit" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_on" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnFlash"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <com.lukelorusso.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image A**

[image]

**Layout B**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- ... The code is same with Layout A -->

    <com.lukelorusso.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAction"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnMenu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image B**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try include the seekBar into another layout as LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAction"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnMenu"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.lukelorusso.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! this code is worked, but is there a better way to do that? you know you add a LinearLayout control.

Comment: you're welcome. I think the problem comes from VerticalSeekBar that's not really integrate in constraint layout. 
Add a linear layout here is not a problem, don't worry about it, you can try maybe to replace LinearLayout by View and it should also works, but linea layout's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

try this : (if if correctly understand what you wants)

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_exit" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFlash"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_on" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnVideo"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnFlash"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnVideo"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btnAction"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAction"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnPicture"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu" />


    <com.lukelorusso.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" // here the view will take all the availanble space
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAction" // bottom to action button
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnMenu" // top to menu button/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks!   but this code `android:layout_height="0dp"` doesn't work, it doesn't take all the avaiable space, and it take 0.

Comment: for me it works. have you clean/build you project ? what is your version of constraint layout ?

Comment: Android studio 3.5.1 and  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

Comment: latest version of constraint layout if 2.0.0-beta2, try use this one.

Comment: No, It doesn't work after I replace with 2.0.0-beta2